# How do I view Transaction Assistant entries with the Kronos API?

Tags: xml, kronos-workforce-central

I want to use the [Kronos Workforce Central API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9812136/3357935) to view and edit queries in the Kronos Transaction Assistant.

I can login to Kronos by submitting an [XML login request](https://forge.cornell.edu/sf/docman/do/downloadDocument/projects.cit_is_customer_apps/docman.root.design_docs/doc5084;jsessionid=rwf6KAPllbRnKbr+f9jwgUjw.tf#page=34) to `/wfc/XmlService`, but I haven't found any documentation for accessing the Transaction Assistant.

```xml
<Kronos_WFC version = '1.0'>
    <Request
        Object = 'System'
        Action = 'Logon'
        Username = 'SomeUsername'
        Password = 'SomePassword'
     />
</Kronos_WFC>
```

How do I retrieve Transaction Manager entries in Kronos WFC v6.3 with the Kronos API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Workforce Central v6.3 Timekeeping Developer's Guide](https://community.kronos.com/s/article/Workforce-Timekeeper-v6-3-Developer-s-Toolkit-Reference-Guide) (*login required*), you can retrieved failed XML transactions from the Transaction Assistant with `<FailedXMLTransaction>`.

> ## FailedXMLTransaction Tag
>
> The FailedXMLTransaction tag provides information about an XML transaction
>   that has failed an attempt to process an XML request. It is used to retrieve or modify failed XML transaction information.
>
> Note: This tag provides information for the Transaction Assistant.

You can use the `Load` action to view entries from the Transaction manager.

> #### Load
>
> Returns all failed transactions for the specified SourceName and
>   TransactionType. You must specify at least one of these properties
>   with the Load action; if you do not, an error is returned.
>
> Return Value Type: Zero or more FailedXMLTransaction tags
>
> Optional Properties: SourceName, TransactionType

**The XML request below retrieves failed Pay Code Edits that were submitted by the Workforce Integration Manager.**

```
<Kronos_WFC version='1.0'>
    <Request Action='Load'>
        <FailedXMLTransaction SourceName='WIM' TransactionType='Pay Code Edits'/>
    <Request>
</Kronos_WFC>
```

As for editing transactions, I unfortunately couldn't find any way to do this with the XML API in v6.3.